# Why there is difference between MS Access and SQL Server for InsertCommand?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ado.net

In this tutorial

for MS Access there is no need to create InsertCommand
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/relationaladonet.aspx

whereas for SQL Server it is needed ?

Is it true ?

Update: I tried it doesn't work with MS Access when inserting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

why are you doing a tutorial on access 2000 / sql-server 2000 anyway?

Comment: I don't think it really matters why OP is doing the tutorial... ;)

Comment: Yes -- here's why:  in the Access approach, he uses the oledbcommandbuilder, which auto-builds the CRUD statements.  In the SQL-approach, he builds the commands manually.  The Access Insert command is being generated by the oledbcommandbuilder.  If something isn't working, I wouldn't assume that this is the problem.  Is it throwing a specific error / have you tried stepping through or error-trapping?